# Right sidebar shows up below content div element

Tags: html, css

The content is centered using margin:0 auto; and the right side bar is floated right. The sidebar goes to the right, however shows up a level below the content box. If theres anything I might have left out, please let me know and I will upload.

Note: Sorry I may have uploaded excess code, but I wanted to upload everything to be sure.

EDIT: The included header file is just div element with height: 50px width: 100%; no problems with that either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="menu1" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Box 2</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="menu3" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Box 3</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="menu1" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Box 2</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="menu3" class="menuItem">
                <h3>Box 3</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.menuItem{
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#content{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#sidebar2{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle out of this: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Any reason you have 2 times in your html navigation, box2 and box3? An didn't understand where is the problem :)

Comment: You also have 2 divs with `id="sidebar"`. IDs *must* be unique, otherwise use a class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=U9LBdMj3fS and sorry I was making a bunch of edits, the second side bar should be sidebar2

Comment: The one that appears below the content is trying to float left I think. Give it id sidebar2 and it should float right at least.

Comment: Its fixed, and I deleted two of the menu boxes in each side bar to remove some extra code in jsfiddle. Also does the chat work in fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move both sidebars before the content div. Generally speaking, a floating block allows blocks after it to be placed by its side, while a non-floating block causes all blocks after it to go below it.

Comment: Thank you! Spent like an hour trying to figure this out. Sorry I thought you can pick 2 answers.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the same ID for more than one HTML element. That's the point of using IDs instead of classes. Use different ID on your sidebars and move them properly with CSS.

Here you got some magic

```
div#wrapper {
    max-width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.menuItem {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#sidebar2 {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/A8Pz3/1/